# Specify the height of table header

Tags: tables, height

I'm new to Lyx and I have a problem. I have the following table and everything is good except that I want to limit the height of header cells. I want them to be shorter that this where each header would contain multiple lines. How I can do that?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule 
\begin{turn}{90}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Zero cost
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Distribution allowed
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
No usage restrictions
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Source code available
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Source code modifications
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Linking with proprietary work
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Derivative work can be proprietary
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
Can be relicensed by anyone
\end{turn}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Non-copyleft (permissive)  & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &       \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Weak copyleft & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &   \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x & x\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Strong copyleft (restrictive)  & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &     \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x & x & x\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Open source license categories. Original source          \cite{kechagia2010open}}
\end{table}
```

Best Regards,

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please post some details of your coding, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4488/15925

Comment: Sorry for that, I have added it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `minipage` for cells in header to limit their width

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\newenvironment{Turn}{\begin{turn}{90}\begin{minipage}{3cm}\raggedright}
{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule 
           & \begin{Turn}
Zero cost
\end{Turn} & \begin{Turn}
Distribution allowed
\end{Turn} & \begin{Turn}
No usage restrictions
\end{Turn} & \begin{Turn}
Source code available
\end{Turn} & \begin{Turn}
Source code modifications
\end{Turn} & \begin{Turn}
Linking with proprietary work
\end{Turn} & \begin{Turn}
Derivative work can be proprietary
\end{Turn} & \begin{Turn}
Can be relicensed by anyone
\end{Turn}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Non-copyleft (permissive)  & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &       \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Weak copyleft & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &   \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x & x\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Strong copyleft (restrictive)  & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &     \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x & x & x\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Open source license categories. Original source          \cite{kechagia2010open}}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi Salim, That look like it would solve my problem perfectly. However, how I add the code to my file? I have no idea about how to do that in Lyx.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to do is to use `\parbox{}` to limit the header width. You can give the size for each parbox as shown below. Another change I would suggest is to use `\ding{51}` and `\ding{55}` instead of `\textsurd` and `x`. they can be found in `pifont` package. In Lyx you can use the insert Tex code facility to insert just the `{\parbox{2cm}{Header}}` inside the table header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule 
\begin{turn}{90}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{Zero cost}}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{Distribution allowed}}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{No usage restrictions}}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{Source code available}}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{Source code modifications}}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{Linking with proprietary work}}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{Derivative work can be proprietary}}
\end{turn} & \begin{turn}{90}
{\parbox{2cm}{Can be relicensed by anyone}}
\end{turn}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Non-copyleft (permissive)  & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &       \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Weak copyleft & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &   \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x & x\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Strong copyleft (restrictive)  & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} &     \textsurd{} & \textsurd{} & x & x & x\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Open source license categories. Original source          \cite{kechagia2010open}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]